# multiple inputs into python function

Tags: python, input

Say I wanted to find the average of a few numbers taken in by the input function. How do I get my function to keep taking in new variables until it runs out of numerical values? Example input code below.

```
print_average() 

Input
$10.00
$20.00
$30.00
```

So i would en up with (a+b+c)/3 = average kind of thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to let a raw\_input repeat until I wanna quit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781445/how-to-let-a-raw-input-repeat-until-i-wanna-quit)

Comment: @Radio- that is not even close to the same question....

Answer (score 3):

You could put all the numbers you want to find the average of in a list, then loop through the list, add all the numbers together in a separate variable (like a running sum), and then divide by the lists length.

```
import sys
def print_average(l):
    sum = 0
    for num in l:
        sum += float(num)
    return sum/len(l)

print print_average(sys.argv[1:])
```

And to run it getting the command line arguments, you would want to do:

```
python test.py 10.00 20.00 30.00
```

Comment: Each $$ value has to be taken in from input... trying to get my head around sys.stdin

My quiz question has each $$ walue on a new line as i wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where you're getting your input from.  It it's from a file then you can read values until EOF.

```
def calc():
    numbers = []
    while True:
        try:
            numbers.append(int(raw_input("Enter number: "))) #or input() for python 3
        except EOFError: # you break user input with ctrl + d  (unix) or ctrl + z (windows)
            print sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
            break
```

Comment: Also, you might want to add print statement right above the print sum(numbers) / len(numbers)