# Continue After Certain Input

Tags: python, loops

Tried using a while loop and get the same error

```
show_name = str(input("Please Enter Show Name: ")).upper()

if show_name in ['SEINFELD', 'JERRY SEINFELD', 'THE SEINFELD SHOW', 'JERRY']:    
    while True:
        seinfeld_keywords = (str(input("Please Enter Seinfeld Keywords: "))).upper()
    if not seinfeld_keywords: 
        print("Sorry, %s Is Not Currently Available.  Please Check Back Soon!" %show_name)
        continue
```

This script is meant to ask the user what TV show they are interested in. If it is not (at this point), Seinfeld, it should print "Show X is Not Available."  I've got that working, but I'd like the script to then start over and ask for another show to be input.  Any suggestions?

```
show_name = str(input("Please Enter Show Name: ")).upper()

if show_name in ['SEINFELD', 'JERRY SEINFELD', 'THE SEINFELD SHOW', 'JERRY']:    
    seinfeld_keywords = (str(input("Please Enter Seinfeld Keywords: "))).upper()  
else: 
    print("Sorry, %s Is Not Currently Available.  Please Check Back Soon!" %show_name)
    continue
```

Comment: You should look into the while loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to let a raw\_input repeat until I wanna quit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781445/how-to-let-a-raw-input-repeat-until-i-wanna-quit)

Comment: continue is not part of loop

Comment: `continue` is only meaningful (or allowed) _inside a loop_.  It means "continue iterating the next item" or "abandon this iteration and start the next one".  (Some other languages use the keyword `next` instead of `continue` --- same action, different way of saying it.)  If there's no loop, there's no next item, and more importantly no place to start the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You need a while loop. I also restructured your code slightly to make it a little clearer:

```
show_name = input("Please Enter Show Name: ").upper()
while show_name not in ('SEINFELD', 'JERRY SEINFELD', 'THE SEINFELD SHOW', 'JERRY'):
    print("Sorry, {} Is Not Currently Available.  Please Check Back Soon!".format(show_name))
    show_name = input("Please Enter Show Name: ").upper()
seinfeld_keywords = input("Please Enter Seinfeld Keywords: ").upper()
```

Comment: That's perfect!  Thank you so much.