# How to reprint the

Tags: python, raw-input

How cab I repeat the raw_input sentence because every time I or the user answers the question written the python say press any key to continue but I want to repeat the question to know if the user want to do any thing else using the programme I wish you can help me.

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781445/how-to-let-a-raw-input-repeat-until-i-want-to-quit?rq=1) (that the site thinks is related) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple code for that

```
x  = raw_input("Enter a command or q to quit")
while ( x != 'q' ) : 
    ## your code goes.
    x  = raw_input("Enter a command or q to quit")
```

This will recursively ask the user for input until he decides to quit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your respond but what does this sympole != mean and thanks

Comment: != means "not equal to"

Comment: Thanks a lot my problem is solved I will really appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

You mean something as follows?

```
bool = True 
while bool:
    input = raw_input(query) #Get raw_input
    if condition: #check if you should end the loop or ask again
        bool = False #end loop
    #your code here
```

bool is used as a boolean to check if the condition has happened, should call it something else such as run_loop or something like that.

Comment: Don't override builtin names.

Comment: Hi thanks alot for your respond just because i want to understand what do bool and do_something() mean and thanks

Comment: @Wombatz this isnt code, its just for him to understand what type the var is.